# JAVA JPA - save to TSV instead of SQL

Tags: java, sql, csv, jpa, persistence

I need to modify a written project in JAVA where it does the following:

Reads json files, and insert them into a SQL DB by using JPA

EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("my-pu");
EntityManager entityManager = emf.createEntityManager();

"Dao.entityManager.persist(Application1)" where Application1 is a class holding the fields.

There is also a persistence.xml where the database url is mentioned.

I need to export the data to a TSV file instead.
Is it possible to make it with JPA?
I prefer not to change the parsing code itself because it contains about 10 tables and 70 columns each.

Comment: you mean CSV perhaps? You won't be doing that with JPA, which is clearly defined as a persistence mechanism to RDBMS datastores

Comment: Thanks, I ended up editing the program and using the DTO's from each object to print the details as lines into a TSV file.